# JMeter - How to extract values from the specific subsample

Tags: jmeter

I have a script like registering flow: the user is registering, getting his id and get a verification URL and id with the email address.

If the script is run with one user, everything is ok, the user reaches the website through his URL, but if the script is run with 2+ users, every user got the URL from the last email.

Can I extract the link from the specific subsample of the email reader sampler?

Or I need to write a script to verify the user id & URL compliance?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using different data for the 2 users (for when they register)? Depending on the format of the response as you register, there may be an id that you can then extract and then push into the next request. What format is the response? Is it JSON or something else?

Regardless, you should be able to use JMeter extractors to extract the id (if it's there) and then use JMeter variables for your subsequent request.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution would be mapping each user to individual mailbox so they won't share one mailbox but had their own. Emails (as well as the credentials) can be parameterized using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

If for some reason it's not possible you can go for [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) instead of the Mail Reader Sampler and filter the messages in the mailbox using [SearchTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!
And could you send me a script example? I'm new at JMeter and also Groovy, so it's hard for me to find smth. thank you in advance